# Configuring isc-dhcp-server.service on Raspbian Jessie

Tags: networking, raspbian-jessie, dhcp, systemd

When I reboot my pi the isc-dhcp-server fails to start

> ```
> root@r2d2:/home/pi# systemctl status  isc-dhcp-server.service
> ● isc-dhcp-server.service - LSB: DHCP server
>    Loaded: loaded (/etc/init.d/isc-dhcp-server)
>    Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Thu 2016-05-19 17:00:02 BST; 55s ago
>   Process: 529 ExecStart=/etc/init.d/isc-dhcp-server start (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)
>
> May 19 17:00:00 r2d2 dhcpd[592]:
> May 19 17:00:00 r2d2 dhcpd[592]: No subnet declaration for eth0 (no IPv4 addresses).
> May 19 17:00:00 r2d2 dhcpd[592]: ** Ignoring requests on eth0.  If this is not what
> May 19 17:00:00 r2d2 dhcpd[592]: you want, please write a subnet declaration
> May 19 17:00:00 r2d2 dhcpd[592]: in your dhcpd.conf file for the network segment
> May 19 17:00:02 r2d2 isc-dhcp-server[529]: Starting ISC DHCP server: dhcpdcheck syslog for diagnostics. ... failed!
> May 19 17:00:02 r2d2 isc-dhcp-server[529]: failed!
> May 19 17:00:02 r2d2 systemd[1]: isc-dhcp-server.service: control process exited, code=exited status=1
> May 19 17:00:02 r2d2 systemd[1]: Failed to start LSB: DHCP server.
> May 19 17:00:02 r2d2 systemd[1]: Unit isc-dhcp-server.service entered failed state.
> Hint: Some lines were ellipsized, use -l to show in full.
> ```

when I restart it from the shell it seems fine

> ```
> root@r2d2:/home/pi# systemctl restart isc-dhcp-server
> root@r2d2:/home/pi# systemctl status  isc-dhcp-server
> ● isc-dhcp-server.service - LSB: DHCP server
>    Loaded: loaded (/etc/init.d/isc-dhcp-server)
>    Active: active (running) since Thu 2016-05-19 17:03:18 BST; 11s ago
>   Process: 781 ExecStart=/etc/init.d/isc-dhcp-server start (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
>    CGroup: /system.slice/isc-dhcp-server.service
>            └─790 /usr/sbin/dhcpd -q -cf /etc/dhcp/dhcpd.conf -pf /var/run/dhcpd.pid eth0
>
> May 19 17:03:16 r2d2 dhcpd[789]: Wrote 0 deleted host decls to leases file.
> May 19 17:03:16 r2d2 dhcpd[789]: Wrote 0 new dynamic host decls to leases file.
> May 19 17:03:16 r2d2 dhcpd[789]: Wrote 0 leases to leases file.
> May 19 17:03:16 r2d2 dhcpd[790]: Server starting service.
> May 19 17:03:18 r2d2 isc-dhcp-server[781]: Starting ISC DHCP server: dhcpd.
> May 19 17:03:18 r2d2 systemd[1]: Started LSB: DHCP server.
> ```

This has been happening since I re-imaged the pi with the latest distro

```
RASPBIAN JESSIE
Full desktop image based on Debian Jessie
Version:May 2016
Release date:2016-05-10
Kernel version:4.4
```

I think this may relate to the new dhcpcd (dhcp client daemon) config, but I do not know exactly how to resolve it.

Does anyone know the cause?
Are there any workarounds?

Answer (score 1):

Look at this link, under the "Not So Fast" section.  Maybe the Fast boot mode, which doesn't wait for network connectivity, is affecting something?

http://blog.dantup.com/2016/04/setting-up-raspberry-pi-raspbian-jessie-to-send-email/